# android objectanimator scaleX only in one direction

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am using ObjectAnimator and cant figure out how to scale in x axe only in one direction for example to right side. Because when im scaling it scales both ways and then my ImageView is out of screen. I know i could add transitionX to prevent going off-screen but a better solution would be scaling in one direction.

```
ObjectAnimator headAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageHead, "scaleX", 1f, 1.5f);
    headAnim.setDuration(1000);
    headAnim.start();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just set the pivot point of the View, using `View.setPivotX()` and `View.setPivotY()`. Set it to 0,0 to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

The param of `View.setPivotX/Y` is a `float` value. It is the absolute value of `width` or `height`, not the percent.